# Change frame of UIView created in interface

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

My app was designed for iPhone 5, but now I'm adding compatibility for other devices.

I have a `UIView`, created in Interface Builder. I want to set a new frame for this view. I am checking the screen's width and height at runtime, but it's not changing the view's frame. Here is my code:

```
//in viewDidLoad:
CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
CGFloat screenWidth = screenRect.size.width;
CGFloat screenHeight = screenRect.size.height;

if (screenHeight == 480 && screenWidth == 320) {
   bottomView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 60, 320, 420);
}
```

Comment: Check auto-resizing mask properties in Interface builder wheather they properly set or not.

Comment: Are you using auto-layout?

Comment: iam not using autolayout @AshrafTawfeeq

Comment: Print out the frame after changing it. And I have a question what does ':' mean?

Comment: You don't have to put both conditions of height and width. Instead you can just put height in your code because every device's height is unique. Just saying coz it reduces your work and saves your time :)

Comment: @AshrafTawfeeq i have changed : to =  . thanx for mentioning

Comment: So does the frame change?

Comment: i have fixed it myself.i had done it before.had forgot

Answer (score 1):

Goto interface builder tap on view, you want to resize, click on Attribute inspector than click on size and select freeform after that in your viewWillAppear resize your view, you can check size of you view by:-

NSLog(@"view frame ==> %@", NSStringFromCGRect(self.view.frame));

Answer (score 0):

Make a class that returns you a screen frame info.

Create a new File with name FullScreen with UIScreen as sub class

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface FullScreen : UIScreen
+ (CGRect)iOS7StyleScreenBounds;
@end


#import "FullScreen.h"

@implementation FullScreen
+ (CGRect)iOS7StyleScreenBounds {
    UIScreen *screen = [UIScreen mainScreen]; CGRect screenRect;
        if (![screen respondsToSelector:@selector(fixedCoordinateSpace)] && UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape([UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation)) {
    screenRect = CGRectMake(screen.bounds.origin.x, screen.bounds.origin.y, screen.bounds.size.height, screen.bounds.size.width);
        } else {
            screenRect = screen.bounds;
      }
      return screenRect;
}
@end
```

Now import this class in your view controller and call like this:

```
self.view.frame = [FullScreen iOS7StyleScreenBounds];
```

Comment: but i want to resize a view only i did not get what your code doing.

Comment: resizing and re-framing of custom views works fine; but the view which is created in interface builder doesnot re-frame

Answer (score 0):

Try Putting the code in

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated;
```

Comment: And just for safer side for orientation issue
if (screenRect.size.width > screenRect.size.height ) 
{
    float width = screenBounds.size.width;
    float height = screenBounds.size.height;
    screenRect.size.height = width;
    screenRect.size.width = height;
}
if (screenHeight ==480 && screenWidth==320) {
         bottomView.Frame:CGRectMake(0, 60, 320, 420);
    }

Answer (score 0):

One definite solution which can work is , you should remove your UIView from xib and create it programmatically.Which can be done by the following code:

```
newView=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 50, 320, 430)];
[newView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor yellowColor]];
[self.view newView];
```

Comment: my view contains 3 buttons and 3 labels , which i will have to create again.not good approach